# How to group and count in sphinx search?

Tags: .net, sphinx

I'm using sphinx dot net client recently in my project. I'm a novice in this area. I manage to fetch the result from sphinx server

This is what my code looks like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchCommand search = new common().ReturnCommand();
            SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery("");
            query.Indexes.Add("SphinxSearch");
            query.MatchMode = MatchMode.Extended;

            query.MaxMatches = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SphinxMaxMathces"]);
            query.Limit = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SphinxLimit"]);
            query.MatchMode = MatchMode.Extended2;

            query.AttributeFilters.Add("CategoryId", 2, false);

            query.Select = "categoryid,SubCategoryId1";

            search.QueryList.Add(query);
            search.Execute();

            foreach (Match match in search.Result.QueryResults[0].Matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Category : {0} , Subcategory : {1} \n ", (int)match.AttributesValues["categoryid"].GetValue(), (int)match.AttributesValues["subcategoryid1"].GetValue());

            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Total {0} Mathches Found \n", search.Result.QueryResults[0].Matches.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

This code is working fine , Now i need to group things and show counts based on sub categories. So for that i had re written my as

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchCommand search = new common().ReturnCommand();
            SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery("");
            query.Indexes.Add("SphinxSearch");
            query.MatchMode = MatchMode.Extended;

            query.MaxMatches = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SphinxMaxMathces"]);
            query.Limit = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SphinxLimit"]);
            query.MatchMode = MatchMode.Extended2;

            query.AttributeFilters.Add("CategoryId", 2, false);

            query.Select = "SubCategoryId1,COUNT(*)";

            query.GroupBy = "SubCategoryId1";

            search.QueryList.Add(query);
            search.Execute();

            foreach (Match match in search.Result.QueryResults[0].Matches)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(" Subcategory : {0} \n ", (int)match.AttributesValues["subcategoryid1"].GetValue());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Total {0} Mathches Found \n", search.Result.QueryResults[0].Matches.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

But this time things got wrong the sphinx is throwing some kind of INTERNAL ERROR, I spend so much time to fix what is wrong but didn't figure out.

Sphinx server returned error status for query. Server message: 'INTERNAL ERROR: the column 'count(*)/count(*)' does not present in result set schema'

this the error which i got.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: "Sphinx server returned error status for query. Server message: 'INTERNAL ERROR: the column 'count(*)/count(*)' does not present in result set schema'" This what the error which i got.